# AG-grid text editor like selection

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Im trying to use ag-grid (enterprise) for a hex editor application. Therefore, I have one Cell per byte and 16 Cells per Row. Now I would like to have an text editor like selection where, if I select a cell in Row and drag my mouse to a Cell in another Row, all the sequential data in between is selected.

[image]

My current approach can create selection like in the image but after I selected a cell in another row I cannot select anything else anymore.

Is there a way to continue selecting cells after the first drag?

Is there another clever way to achieve this kind of selection with ag-grid?

```
const gridOptions = {
//...
enableRangeSelection: true,
onRangeSelectionChanged: function(event) {
    gridOptions.api.getCellRanges().forEach(range => {
        var startRow = range.startRow.rowIndex;
        var stopRow =  range.endRow.rowIndex;
        var firstCol = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumn("hex0");
        var lastCol = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumn("hex15");

        if (startRow == stopRow){
            return;
        } else if(startRow > stopRow){
             //clear selection
            gridOptions.api.clearRangeSelection();

            //Select row of start cell to the right
            gridOptions.api.addCellRange({
                rowStartIndex: startRow,
                rowEndIndex: startRow,
                columnStart: range.startColumn,
                columnEnd: firstCol,
            });

            //select all full rows which are not start or stop rows
            for(var i = startRow + 1; i<stopRow - 1; i++){
                gridOptions.api.addCellRange({
                    rowStartIndex: i,
                    rowEndIndex: i,
                    columnStart: firstCol,
                    columnEnd: lastCol,
                });
            }

            //select final row from left to stop Cell
            gridOptions.api.addCellRange({
                rowStartIndex: stopRow,
                rowEndIndex: stopRow,
                columnStart: lastCol,
                columnEnd: range.columns[range.columns.length - 1],
            });

        } else if(startRow < stopRow){
            //...
        }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: it would be helpfull if you can share [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self%2Dcontained%20correct%20example.)